# Is there a way in CSS by which I can access elements inside element. First element, Second Element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have

```
  <div class='r1'>
               <div> Apple </div>
               <div> Banana </div>
               <div> Orange </div>
               <div> Tulip </div>
  </div>
```

I wanted to access each element inside r1 but I have to give each of them a separate id or class. Is there any way I just access it based on their number of position.

Such as

```
  .r1:first-child{
     color:red;
   }

  .r1:second-child{
     color:blue;
    }
```

Comment: Learn about nth-child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:nth-child()` selector. For example:

```
.r1:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}

.r1:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue;
}
```

You can also cool formula stuff like:

```
/* Will make every 5th element red, starting at the second one */
.r1:nth-child(5n+1) {
  color: red;
}

/* Will make the odd div elements blue */
.r1:nth-child(odd) div {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: You mean div...

Answer (score 0):

```css
.ri:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}

.ri:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue;
}
```

etc.